# how do you get <div> value using angularjs? example <div id="text">Text</div>

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

how do you get  value using angular js?

how can get Text content using angularjs?

Comment: What are you trying to do? We need more details to know how best to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

If i got your question right, then you mean to ask how can we set the content in dom using angularjs. I am explaining a very simple example here.

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="personController">

First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
<br>
Full Name: <p>{{firstName + " " + lastName}}</p>

</div>

<script>
function personController($scope) {
    $scope.firstName= "John";
    $scope.lastName= "Doe";
}
</script>
```

in angularjs we initialize the application with ng-app, ng-controller defines the scope, here it is personController. in personController defination we are settting two variable firstname and last name. now these 2 set value can be get using this "{{ }}". There are many other ways of setting value but i will recommend you to go through some angular basic tutorials so that you can understand everything better.

Answer (score -1):

Use ng-model attribute...

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="personController">

<div ng-model="example">This is an example</div>

</div>

<script>
function personController($scope) {

var ex = $scope.example;

}
</script>
```